# How to insert the value in selected cell only of nstableview

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I am trying to insert value in a particular cell only, for example how to insert value in (2,3) 2nd row and 3rd column. i know how to insert value in a table but i don't know how to insert value in selected cell.

Comment: I thought you can only select a complete row?!

Answer (score 0):

```
– tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:
```

The intersection of column and row gives you the `cell`.

You need to update the datasource in this datasource method.